# nib button crashing app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a xib that is connected to a viewController (.h and .m). I have created a new button in this in the storyboard area and connected it to the .h as `- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender;` but when I try the button it crashes the app as:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationItemButtonView cameraButton:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13e51a690'
```

I have no idea what would cause this since it is connected to the viewcontroller.

[image]

Comment: Are you using `storyboards` OR `NIB` files?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of what exactly you have the button wired up to? `[UINavigationItemButtonView cameraButton:]` makes it sound like the method is being called on the button itself and not the view controller.

Comment: To clarify, I mean a screenshot of the Connections inspector in the right-hand sidebar of Interface Builder after having selected your button.

Comment: just added it @BergQuester

Comment: I don't see in the screenshot what exactly it connects to. But anyway, it makes no sense.

Comment: You connected to a controller bu the error message comes from a view.

Comment: @StudentT the xib file is being loaded as a camera overlay like this `ControlsViewController *overlayViewController = [[ControlsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ControlsViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = overlayViewController.view;`

Comment: can u post your full code?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a moment.... You said you've connected to a UIViewController but the error message is UINavigationItemButtonView...

I think you've connected your button to the view, but that's not correct. You're supposed to set the owner in File Owner to the controller then connect the button to it. YOU DONT WANT TO CONNECT THEB UTTON TO THE VIEW.

Do you see "File's Owner" in your screenshot. You're meant to connect your button to it.

Comment: i have `- (IBAction)cameraButton:(id)sender {NSLog(@"button pushed");
}` in the .M file.

Comment: The Files Owner is set to my ViewController class and the button is connected to the .h file so I think it is set up correct right?

Comment: There's no such thing as connecting to .h. You connect your button to the file owner. Did you make the connection?

Comment: Yes it is connected. I dragged the arrow up to the file owner and selected the IBAction I created. That means its connected correct?

Comment: Yes. That means it's connected. Well... You claim the file owner is the controller and you did connect to it. But the error message says the button's connected to the view instead... not sure why.

Comment: Would be because this XIB is being loaded from the imagepicker as an overlay?

Comment: I don't think so. Sorry, I can't help you. Let's wait for someone else.